# Is it possible to have an hidden recording of camera device with ID0 and a possible preview stream also ID 0 at the same time?

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera2

I build an app where the user has an FAB to start some hidden image recording with `camera2 API` and some other location stuff - now the user has the option to open a preview with an item from navigation drawer. The problem is that if I start hidden recording over FAB and then click to open the preview, the statecallback `onDisconnected` from `CameraDevice` is called and the hidden recording is disabled due to CameraDevice with ID 0 is no longer available.

My code is like the sample `Camera2Video` from Google:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video

```java
    private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewBuilder;
    private CameraCaptureSession mPreviewSession;

    /**
     * A {@link Semaphore} to prevent the app from exiting before closing the camera.
     */
    private Semaphore mCameraOpenCloseLock = new Semaphore(1);

    /**
     * {@link CameraDevice.StateCallback} is called when {@link CameraDevice} changes its status.
     */
    private CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
            Log.d(TAG, "onOpened: ");
            File dir = new File(mNextVideoDirPath);
            if(dir.mkdirs()) {
                startRecordingVideo();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(context,
                        "Error: Could not start recording. Directory for saved files could not be created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
            cameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int error) {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
            cameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }
    };
```

If I do at first the preview and then start the hidden recording the preview freezes and hidden recording starts.

I have an Huawei P30 pro and tried to just change the ID of camera device but instead of front camera it's crashing.

So is there a differnt approach for some use case like this or isn't it even possible to do so **OR** how can I prevent some disconnection?

**UPDATE**

I found an article about multiple streams from on e device on medium from android developers
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/using-multiple-camera-streams-simultaneously-bf9488a29482

Maybe I can add those targets before I do the stuff..
Something like this:
https://gist.github.com/owahltinez/f615e13bfc3497a0bd5d1427eae6c54f#file-using-multiple-camera-streams-01-kt

**UPDATE END**

If necessary I can provide some more code, but it's most like the sample from google.

Thank you for your time!